# Notation of discs

Tags: general-topology

This is the text in question:

> A closed disk is a set of the form $\{x: \|x−y\| \leq r\}$ for some $y$ and $r>0$. Whenever $z$ does not belong to that disk, we have $\|z−y\|>r$, and the entire disk $\{w:\|w−z\|<\|z−y\|−r\}$ does not intersect the first disk.

I am confused by the notation. This is what I understand:

$\{x: \|x−y\| \leq r\}$ means a closed disc centered at the point $x$, and $y$ is an arbitrary point on the closed disc, and the distance between $x$ and $y$ is less than or equal to some positive number $r$. $\|x−y\|$ is essentially the distance between $x$ and $y$, with $x$ being the "center," so $y$ units away from $x$.

If we have some point $z$ that is not on this disc, why is $\|z−y\|>r$ true? If we consider this picture:

[image]

It's not true, because the distance between $z$ and $y$ is less than $r$.

I also don't understand where the $\{w:\|w−z\|<\|z−y\|−r\}$ part comes from, but maybe after I understand why $\|z−y\|>r$ is true, it might make more sense.

Comment: The first disk that you mention is centered at $y$. Not at $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r>0$.

Then $\overline{D}\left(y,r\right)=\left\{ x\mid\left\Vert x-y\right\Vert \leq r\right\} $
is a closed disk centered at $y$.

Here $z\notin\overline{D}\left(y,r\right)$
means exactly that $\left\Vert z-y\right\Vert >r$ or equivalently
$s:=\left\Vert z-y\right\Vert -r>0$.

Then we have disk $D\left(z,s\right)=\left\{ x\mid\left\Vert x-z\right\Vert <s\right\} $ centered at $z$.

If $u\in\overline{D}\left(y,r\right)\cap D\left(z,s\right)$ then
$\left\Vert u-y\right\Vert \leq r$ and $\left\Vert u-z\right\Vert <s$.

However then $\left\Vert z-y\right\Vert \leq\left\Vert z-u\right\Vert +\left\Vert u-y\right\Vert <s+r=\left\Vert z-y\right\Vert $
and a contradiction is found.

The conclusion is that $\overline{D}\left(y,r\right)\cap D\left(z,s\right)=\emptyset$.

I hope this takes away your confusion. The main cause of that is mentioned in my comment.